# HTTP Error 500.31 - ANCM Failed to Find Native Dependencies

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I upgraded an existing application from asp.net core web API 2.0 to 3.1. When I run the application locally, application runs fine without any errors, but when I deployed the application to the same server where the 2.0 application was running, I got an error saying "ANCM failed to find Native dependencies". 
Below is the screen shot:

[image]

From the provided link:
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1

I was able to find out that I need to install .net core 3.1. I am not sure if I need to install on my server:

ASP.NET Core Runtime 3.1.3
OR
SDK 3.1.201

I already have few 2.1 applications running on the server so I don't want the older applications to stop working if I upgrade to 3.1 . I have IIS installed on the server. Its a Microsoft windows NT version 6.2 DataCenter edition terminal server and my application that I am trying to deploy is .net core 3.1

I just wanted to know whether I should install ASP.NET Core Runtime 3.1.3 or SDK 3.1.201

and installing any of these on the server wont affect the applications that are running on 2.0 .net core framwork.

any help will be apprecaited.

Comment: How did you publish your application? What `dotnet publish` command did you use exactly? Make that part of the question or you are asking others to guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each .NET Core will define which version it uses and will use that SDK or runtime. Installing another SDK or runtime will not impact previously installed versions.

If your just hosting and not doing any development on the server then you only need to install the runtime. If any development will be taking place you will need the SDK.

Comment: Thanks, but should I install SDK or runtime on the server

Comment: If your just hosting and not doing any development on the server then you only need to install the runtime. If any development will be taking place you will need the SDK